# How to pass a request in template tag in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a web based application in Django. My application is full of widget(not a Django-widgets) which is used for load the different types data using Ajax. For example a 'student' name widgets are loading list of users and a 'teacher' name widget are loading the list of all teacher in a school. To doing this i am getting some following doubts in mind:

I am using templatetag (take a look on the code http://codepad.org/2Ug9Ct3n). In this code when i am doing `if request and request.is_ajax():`it showing me an error `None object has no attribute ajax`. The problem is this that i am not able to include request properly. I have already make changes into my `setting.py` i.e.

```
 TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
 'django.core.context_processors.static',
 'django.core.context_processors.request',
 'django.core.context_processors.media',
 )
```

If that thing has no solution then would it be possible for me to write the whole template tag part in views.py? and how?

Instead of that if there are any possibility please post them as a answer!

Any help will be appreciable

Comment: This needs to go in the view, not as a template tag.

Comment: Please don't ask [your unsolved question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731672/getting-the-request-is-none-in-template-tags-in-django) again, just enrich the question by more detail(for example explain where the `None object has no attribute ajax` occurs)

Comment: @okm I have deleted that question..and going to more explain on this part

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Would you please tell me how :This issue is also a part of question

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your view (which you haven't posted) is rendering the template with a `RequestContext`. This happens automatically for you if you're using class based views or the `render` shortcut.

However, if your're using `render_to_response`, you need to do the following:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                              my_data_dictionary,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks for the replying, The code i pasted on codepad [link](http://codepad.org/2Ug9Ct3n) written in template tag. There is no views.py written for that methods. Should it be? Because i have already did **render_to_response** in **ajax_print_widget** method which are defined in template tag. Is this wrong ?

Comment: The template tag is included in a template. That template is rendered by a view. That view must use `RequestContext`.

Comment: This is [my widget_area.html](http://codepad.org/kUaMeBas). please Take a look line No. 24 **{% render_widget widget_settings %}**. Here render_widget is the template tag and to render it a method has been define (as you saw on the above posted code). What i am going to display in widgets are coming from this with the combination of **render_widget and ajax_print_widget** method. As you saw that i am  doing render_to_response to ajax_print..method. Now you said to render this template.html also which contains these template tags. I did that by defining a method in ..continue in next comment

Comment: [views.py](http://codepad.org/6BF9mwmN). But to make a link i need also to add a Url Pattern for this template and i also did [urls.py](http://codepad.org/DJd38aTy) see the 6th line. But i don't have any data to rendet this template then what should it be in **my_data_instance**.Anyhow i run the code and still i am getting the value of request in template tag in NONE. I checked with **pdb.set_trace()** and it shows that without opening plugin/widget_area.html in browser it is not enetering into the method i.e. **widget_data** . What should i do ?
I didn't got any right tutorial for this :(

Comment: I'm not going to have time to help you with this any further. I hope you get it working.